# What is the name of a graph with local clustering coefficients equal to zero?

Tags: graph-theory

I am struggling to find in literature a name for a kind of graph where all local clustering coefficients are equal to zero (or, at least, bounded).
For instance, domino, a subset of cacti and all linear graphs belong to this class. 
I do not know if such objects are named.

Comment: If you actually want *equal* to zero, isn't this the same as being triangle-free?

Comment: Is *cactii* supposed to be plular of *cactius*? There is no such word.

Comment: @Joshua: hum, yes. I forgot that expression. I answers the question with that.

Comment: @Emil: Well, it is used in biology and french. I did not research for equivalent in other fields or in english.

Comment: @aluriak No, the word used in biology etc. is *cactus*, with plural *cacti*.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i did not see my additional *i*, which is a mistake. I now understand your remark. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments by [Joshua Grochow](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/129/joshua-grochow), this is a definition of *triangle-free graph*.